# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-intent

Description:

I am getting ClassCast Exception while i am clicking to button on the title bar.
My source code is as follows:

**My activity code:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.about_us) {

        if (isInternetConnected()) {
            System.out.println("about us");
            startActivity(new Intent(GridDisplayActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
        } else {
            setAlertBox("No Internet Connection");
        }
    }
    if (v.getId() == R.id.hard_copy) {

        if (isInternetConnected()) {
            System.out.println("hard copy");
            startActivity(new Intent(GridDisplayActivity.this,HardCopyActivity.class));
        } else {
            setAlertBox("No Internet Connection");
        }
    }

}
```

**Custom Application Code:**

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

private Map<String, List<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>>> mActivityTaskMap;

public CustomApplication() {
    mActivityTaskMap = new HashMap<String, List<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>>>();
}

public void removeTask(CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?> task) {
    for (Entry<String, List<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>>> entry : mActivityTaskMap.entrySet()) {
        List<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>> tasks = entry.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            if (tasks.get(i) == task) {
                tasks.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (tasks.size() == 0) {
            mActivityTaskMap.remove(entry.getKey());
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void addTask(Activity activity, CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?> task) {
    String key = activity.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    List<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>> tasks = mActivityTaskMap.get(key);
    if (tasks == null) {
        tasks = new ArrayList<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>>();
        mActivityTaskMap.put(key, tasks);
    }

    tasks.add(task);
}

public void detach(Activity activity) {
    List<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>> tasks = mActivityTaskMap.get(activity.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    if (tasks != null) {
        for (CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?> task : tasks) {
            task.setActivity(null);
        }
    }
}

public void attach(Activity activity) {
    List<CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?>> tasks = mActivityTaskMap.get(activity.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    if (tasks != null) {
        for (CustomAsyncTask<?,?,?> task : tasks) {
            task.setActivity(activity);
        }
    }
  }
```

}

**The logs that i am getting are:**

```
07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.bespoken.android.provider.CustomApplication
07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.bespoken.android.GridDisplayActivity.onSaveInstanceState(GridDisplayActivity.java:567)
07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1114)
07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1184)
 07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469)
 07-26 11:06:10.567: E/AndroidRuntime(381):     ... 12 more
```

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is CustomApplication here and you you are declaring it in your xml file

Comment: GridDisplayActivity.java:567 this line is the culprit.

Comment: what is there on line no. 567 of GridDisplayActivity

Comment: There is an asynTask along with the rotational handling so on line no. 567 is "((CustomApplication) getApplication()).detach(this);" which has been there inside public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do `(CustomApplication)getApplication()` but instead  have a `static` `CustomApplication` field, say `mInstance`, in the `CustomApplication` class, set it in the `CustomApplication.onCreate` to `this` and use it wherever you want to access `CustomApplication'`s methods.

```
class CustomApplication extends Application
{

private static CustomApplication mInstance;

@Override
void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static CustomApplication getInstance() { return mInstance; }

public void mySpecificMethod() { .... }

}
```

Then you call from where you need it:

```
CustomApplication.getInstance()->mySpecificMethod()
```

Comment: @Richa Laad I've edited the answer suggesting a piece of code

Comment: when i am using the (CustomApplication.getInstance()).detach(this) on an activity's onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState), i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Richa Laad Do you have CustomApplication in your manifest.xml <application ... android:name="CustomApplication"?

Comment: Ohh..I have not specified as was dealing with custom application for the first time

Comment: **Thanks** alex for your help. I have added the Custom Application in manifest.xml file and it worked for me.